# Green outlines appearing around links in Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I started noticing green lines appearing around links, search bars, and drop down menus in Chrome. Restarting my computer did not fix the problem. I'm running Windows 10. I've noticed this problem on Twitter, Poshmark, and Reddit among many other sites. [Here are a few examples of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XLzp.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by going through my extensions and disabling them individually. This problem is caused by the RebatesMe extension.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the three dotted button of chrome in top right corner > Settings > Scroll down > Advanced > Scroll to end of page > Reset settings to their original defaults > Reset settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an anti-virus/anti-malware that provides browser protection then that could be causing it as well. What AV are you using?